# Thread scheduling overhead and context switching

Tags: java, scheduling, context-switch

i just want to clear my concept on multithreading overheads.In a java book "Java Concurrency In Practice"by  Brian Göetz i read following paragraph in Chapter-11 section-11.1.

---

*"While the goal maybe to improve performance overall, using multiple threads always introduces some performance costs compared to the single threaded approach. These include the overhead associated with coordinating between
threads(locking,signaling,synchronization),increased context switching,thread creation and teardown,and scheduling overhead."*

---

Why did he separate context switching overhead and scheduling overhead. Is thread scheduling overhead not same as context switch overhead. I am confused in both concepts.

Answer (score 0):

In simple words:

**Context switch** means in your process one thread would enter in a wait/sleep state and other would enter in run state i.e. start executing. This does means storing the current state of thread that enters wait state and retrieving the other threads current state inorder to start execution of the same from the point where it entered wait state.

**Scheduling overhead** means once threads enter into runnable state (ready to execute), OS would reschedule it to one of the processor along with resources it might need.

Comment: "Os would reschedule it to one of the processor" . But this sentence is same as OS would restore its context in one of the processor .i.e. It is context switching then where is the difference?

Comment: Assume you already have thread in runnable state but say all the processor are busy, OS is not going to schedule your thread as your thread is already running. Now if your thread say enters wait state, it would just restore current thread and would pick up the thread already in wait queue and would start executing it.

Comment: And all this will involve context switching ultimately due to scheduling threads. i.e. both are same.

Comment: No they aren't but you can say context switch for a particular instance meaning it will bear the cost of scheduling too later down the line.